# How long should ruby gem native extensions take to build?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I am running the following command on a brand new MacBook Pro with 4GB of RAM:

```
sudo gem install json nokogiri uglifier therubyracer -V
```

It shows some progress, but has been stuck at the following message for over 1.5 hours:

```
...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.6/tests/test_json_unicode.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.6/tests/test_json_addition.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.6/tests/test_json_generate.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.6/tests/test_json_encoding.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.6/tests/test_json_generic_object.rb
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.7.6/tests/test_json.rb
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
```

In Activity Monitor, I see that `xcrun` is using 95% of the CPU and has been doing so for the entire duration and it has not completed compiling the json gem.  How long does this building process take?  Is there any way I can speed it up?

Comment: therubyracer may be quite slow, since it might be trying to build libv8. The others should be quite fast though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this by installing Xcode from the App Store (even though I had already installed Xcode command line tools) and then running Xcode.

To verify this was done correctly, run the following command:

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

It should show:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: (If you didn't install the Command Line Tools in the first place, I believe you'd need to go to Xcode > Preferences > Downloads and install them from there.)